# Apex Trigger Optimization

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a child object called "Opportunity_Team__c" whose parent is Opportunity.

This Opportunity_Team__c object has 3 fields

```
Opportunity__c (lookup to Opportunity)
Role__c (which is a picklist) 
and 
User__c(which is a lookup to User)
```

Also in Task object we have a custom field called "Task Group Owner" which is a picklist and has the same picklist entries as in Opportunity_Team__c.Role__c

This image can be helpful

[image]

Whenever there is an update happening in Opportunity_Team__c record I need to query all the records in Task object with the below join and update the ownerId of the task with the latest value in Opportunity_Team__c.User__c

```
Task.WhatId = Opportunity_Team__c.Opportunity__c
&&
Task.Task_Group_Owner__c = Opportunity_Team.Role__c
```

I have developed the following trigger to achieve this.

Is there any way to optimize or improve this code ?

```
trigger OppTeamReAssignTaskTrigger on Opportunity_Team__c (after update) {

  List<Task> mastertasklist = new List<Task>();
  Set<Id> oids = new Set<Id>();

    for(Opportunity_Team__c ot : trigger.new)
    {
        oids.add(ot.Opportunity__c);
    }

    mastertasklist = [SELECT OwnerId, WhatId, Task_Group_Owner__c FROM Task WHERE WhatId IN :oids];

    List<Task> reassignTaskList = new List<Task>();

    for(Opportunity_Team__c ot : trigger.new)
    {
        for(Task t : mastertasklist)
        {
            if(ot.Opportunity__c == t.WhatId && ot.Role__c == t.task_group_owner__c)
            {
                t.OwnerId = ot.User__c;
            }
        }
    }

    update mastertasklist;    

}
```

EDIT:

**Is there any way to modify the code so that I do not have to use two for-loops ?**

Comment: Are you running into a specific issue. Asking *"Can my code be optimized?"* isn't really on topic here.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Updated my post

Comment: Yes, you need two for loops, but they need not be multiplicative for loops. The obvious problem is that you'll eventually hit CPU governor limits. I'm writing something up now.

Comment: You should add a role filter to your query in addition to the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from where you get the masterTaskList, you should create a map so you can easily find the records you're looking for.

```
trigger OppTeamReAssignTaskTrigger on Opportunity_Team__c (after update) {

    Set<Id> oids = new Set<id>();
    Map<Opportunity_Team__c, Id> oppRoleMap = new Map<Opportunity_Team__c, Id>();
    // Create a map of Opportunity/Role to User Id
    for(Opportunity_Team__c record: Trigger.new) {
      oids.add(record.Opportunity__c);
      oppRoleMap.put(
        new Opportunity_Team__c(
          Opportunity__c=record.Opportunity__c, 
          Role__c=record.Role__c),
      record.User__c);
    }
    Task[] masterTaskList = [SELECT OwnerId, WhatId, Task_Group_Owner__c FROM Task WHERE WhatId IN :oids],
      recordUpdateList = new Task[0];
    // Use opportunity/role combination to find new owner
    for(Task record: masterTaskList) {
      Opportunity_Team__c key = new Opportunity_Team__c(
          Opportunity__c=record.WhatId, 
          Role__c=record.Task_Group_Owner__c);
      Id value = oppRoleMap.get(key);
      // Update only if the user differs from the task
      if(value != null && value != record.OwnerId) {
        record.OwnerId = value;
        recordUpdateList.add(record);
      }
    }
    update recordUpdateList;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
for(Opportunity_Team__c ot : trigger.new)
{
    for(Task t : mastertasklist)
    {
        if(ot.Opportunity__c == t.WhatId && ot.Role__c == t.task_group_owner__c)
```

is an example of a pattern whose name I don't know, but which might be called something like "combinatorial search": essentially, performing a search by iterating over multiple lists until items match up. It is not an efficient pattern.

Instead of doing this, you can simply iterate over your Opportunity Team objects once (as you already do at the top of the trigger) and construct a Map of Opportunity Id to Team object to obtain the relevant ownership details.

```
Map<Id, Opportunity_Team__c> opportunityToOppTeam = new Map<Id, Opportunity_Team__c>();
```

Within `for` loop over `trigger.new`, add code to populate this map:

```
if (ot.Role__c == t.task_group_owner__c) { 
    opportunityToOppTeam.put(ot.Opportunity__c, ot);
}
```

Then, the nested `for` loops simplify to a single loop with an update performed only on relevant objects.

```
for (Task t : mastertasklist) {
    Opportunity_Team__c ot = opportunityToOppTeam.get(t.WhatId);
    if (t.OwnerId != ot.User__c) {
        t.OwnerId = ot.User__c;
        reassignTaskList.add(t);
    }
 }
```

Then you update `reassignTaskList`, which is currently an unused variable.